# How can I redirect or close a website on timer?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, timer

I have a website (built in Wordpress) that needs to close after a visitor has been there for 5 minutes. (The people visiting are taking a survey that links out to this page and I need to get them back to the survey after browsing the outside website for five minutes). Displaying a countdown timer in a top corner would be great but not necessary.

I figured out how to get Javascript to close a page on a timer BUT I want the visitors to be able to browse multiple pages without a) me having to place the timer on every page and b) the timer resetting.

This is the webpage: http://www.cancerclinicalstudyguide.com

Thanks

Comment: A webpage can be closed not a website

Comment: use localStorage to save timer

Comment: do you have control of the website opening yours?

Answer (score 1):

If i am right, you have a survey, redirect user to 3rd party website and bring back to original site after some timer. The short answer can't be done directly as it would involve adding some scripts to third party side.

### Solution

You can use iframe for the same. The dom structure would be somewhere along the lines of

```
.container
  iframe
  .timer
  form
```

Now comes the tricky part, set `iframe` display to none. Create two functions `showFrame` and `hideFrame`. The name says most of it all, but remember to toggle visibility of form also as you don't want that to be displayed on other page. Also added a timer just in case you want a clock.

#### Event to show website

When you reach this point call function `showFrame` remember to set `src` attribute for iframe. and call `setTimeout` function with `hideFrame` function and the time you want user back to your site.

#### Cleaning up a little

Here is some basic css that might help you along the way

```
iframe {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.timer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve this.

1. Use [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) and use setInterval to update the cookie every second
2. Use AJAX to dynamically load the content (This can be a bit of a hassle)

You could also not use a timer. I don't really get why you want to restrict the time the users have.